# What does "The weather naturally also matters" mean?

Tags: meaning

> **The weather naturally also matters.** Fewer spectators will visit your arena in bad weather, but those who come will be more interested in buying more expensive tickets and sitting under aroof. It is therefore possible that your total income will be similar in any weather, provided there enough appropriate stands.

What does it mean ?

Comment: Could you provide some additional context?

Comment: Ok, I already edited.

Comment: Why was there a doubt in the first place? Did you imagine anything beyond the obvious? Just curious!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no idioms in this sentence. It's just worded a bit clumsily.

Here **naturally** means *obviously*; the seeming link between weather and nature is just coincidence and not part of the usage. And **the weather matters** means that the weather has an effect on something, in this case, your income as an arena operator.

The sentence could be rephrased as:

*Obviously, the weather also has an effect.*